# Disable specific global var declaration check in TypeScript

Tags: google-chrome, typescript, global-variables, webstorm

I'm writing an extension for Chrome in WebStorm IDE. Problem is that TypeScript compiler keeps whining about '`chrome` variable not defined'. If I silence it with `declare var chrome: any;`, then it will whine about '`chrome` variable might not have been initialized'.

Is there solution to this? Define global explicitly in `tsconfig` or maybe there is specific typedef file for Chrome runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a specific typedef for the Chrome runtime, to solve exactly your problem: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/chrome/chrome.d.ts. If you add that, everything should work nicely.

You'll want to set this up using [Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings), rather than doing it directly. Not clear whether you're already familiar with that, this should require something like:

```
# Install Typings on your system
npm install typings --global

# Install the Chrome type definitions from DefinitelyTyped ('dt')
typings install dt~chrome --global --save
```

More generally, your `declare var` statement above is enough to disable TypeScript's checking of the `chrome` variable and will make it compile successfully, if you don't want to use the proper type definitions above (or if you can't find any in other cases like this).

The warning you're still seeing there is just from WebStorm. I'm not sure exactly what's required to silence that, but I would expect moving it to an external type definition to work. Just add the same code - `declare var chrome: any` - to a new chrome.d.ts file, and make sure it's included your compilation files (probably happens automatically). That should do it.

Comment: Thanks, also, installing global prewritten `dt` with one-liner is more convenient than manually write it from scratch each time you change dev machine %)